# User.Identity.Name is empty when using autofac AutofacWebTypesModule

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 4` and `Autofac`.  I have a `WebWorkContext` class that I inject in various places in my solution to get the current employee's details.

Here is my Autofac registrations in my global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     // Autofac
     ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

     builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());

     builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

     builder.RegisterType<WebWorkContext>().As<IWorkContext>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

     IContainer container = builder.Build();
     DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

My WebWorkContext class:

```
public class WebWorkContext : IWorkContext
{
     private readonly IEmployeeService employeeService;
     private readonly HttpContextBase httpContext;

     public WebWorkContext(IEmployeeService employeeService, HttpContextBase httpContext)
     {
          this.employeeService = employeeService;
          this.httpContext = httpContext;
     }

     public Employee CurrentEmployee
     {
          get
          {
               return GetCurrentEmployee();
          }
     }

     protected Employee GetCurrentEmployee()
     {
          string identityName = this.httpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToLower();

          // Do what I need to do to get employee details from
          // the database with identityName
     }
}
```

I would put a break point on:

```
string identityName = this.httpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToLower();
```

`identityName` is always empty. Not sure why? Am I missing something?

How I use the WebWorkContext class:

```
public class CommonController : Controller
{
     private readonly IWorkContext workContext;

     public CommonController(IWorkContext workContext)
     {
          this.workContext = workContext;
     }

     public ActionResult EmployeeInfo()
     {
          Employee employee = workContext.CurrentEmployee;

          EmployeeInfoViewModel viewModel = Mapper.Map<EmployeeInfoViewModel>(employee);

          return PartialView(viewModel);
     }
}
```

I'm using `Visual Studio 2012`.

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using? Windows, form, etc?

Comment: Windows. I have authentication mode to Windows in my web.config but it is still empty. I just had `<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>`

Answer (score 1):

The website uses IIS that comes with Visual Studio 2012. I wasn't aware that I needed to disable anonymous authentication and enable Windows authentication on the web project itself. It works now.  Here are the steps that I followed if any one else has the same problem:

IIS Express

- Click on your project in the Solution Explorer to select the project.
- If the Properties pane is not open, open it (F4).
- In the Properties pane for your project:

  - Set "Anonymous Authentication" to "Disabled".
  - Set "Windows Authentication" to "Enabled".